# It is possible to find hidden value in js function via requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Is it possible to download the code from the javascript function on the website through requests?
What I mean:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'link'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=2)
print(r.html.text)
```

Output:

```
Hello
Some text on site
function randomname() { 
if  (checkbox() == true)   
document.getElementById('randomcode').value  = '123456789023'; 
else alert('Checkbox not clicked!'); } 

randomname(); 

completef("1823947239d23dc23dsar238rt3r")
```

And now i want to get two values:

123456789023

1823947239d23dc23dsar238rt3r

I tried to find it with

```
r.html.search("checkbox");
r.html.search("completef");
```

but unfortunately I failed :(

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: Here is a case where you DON'T want the Javascript to be executed, so the regular `requests` would be a better choice than `requests_html`.  All you want is the text of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your output as:

```
output = """
Hello
Some text on site
function randomname() { 
if  (checkbox() == true)   
document.getElementById('randomcode').value  = '123456789023'; 
else alert('Checkbox not clicked!'); } 

randomname(); 

completef("1823947239d23dc23dsar238rt3r")
"""
```

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
randomcode = re.search("document.getElementById\('randomcode'\).value  = '(\d+)';", output).group(1)
completef = re.search('completef\("([a-z0-9]+)"\)', output).group(1)
```

Make sure to put a \ infront of every special character like the (,) etc and then use \d+ to search for numbers or [a-z0-9]+ to search for numbers and characters.

Comment: Thanks :) Working :)